# Вопросы по docker'у

Tags: linux, docker

Зашел сегодня на vps и увидел загрузку cpu под 100%, потом посмотрел статистику по контейнерам и заметил такую занимательную вещь:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O
kibana              96.45%              536.8 MB / 536.9 MB   99.99%              884.5 MB / 306.2 MB   2.682 TB / 5.369 GB
```

Отсюда несколько вопросов:

1. Как ограничить использование cpu докером или может есть софт, который сам прибивает процессы, если они выходят за определенные рамки?
2. Что значат 2 последних столбца и откуда терабайты в последнем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Документация](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources), сэр. Можно настроить пропорцию выделяемого контейнеру (конкретному!) процессорного времени с помощью параметра `cpu-shares` (по умолчанию "всем поровну", по 1024); а можно задать параметры для CFS: `cpu-quota` процессорного времени за `cpu-period` реального: настраиваются оба, целыми числами в микросекундах (1000..1 000 000). Все параметры задаются при `docker run`. **Shares мягче**, с ними контейнеру позволяется забирать почти весь процессор, если больше им никто особо не пользуется; когда CFS ставит "жёсткий потолок на все времена".
2. Общий объём операций ввода/вывода над "блочными устройствами", например дисками. Чтение одних и тех же данных, при условии отсутствия кэширования, будет каждый раз увеличивать этот счётчик, поэтому это число вполне себе может превышать общий объём всех подключенных устройств. То же самое с записью: перезапись данных счётчиком учитывается, как обычная запись.